# Can't reduce space with \vskip between parts of vertically splitted rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

In a multipart rectangle i want to reduce the space between the parts. For a horizontally splitted rectangle i achieved that with an `\hskip` after the `\nodepart` command.

For a vertically splitted rectangle i tried it analogously and replaced `\hskip` with `\vskip`. Unfortunately the compiler doesn't like `\vskip` here an ends with an error. The appended code illustrates that.

Why `vskip` doesn't work in my example and how could i alternatively reduce the space between vertically splitted parts of the rectangle?

---

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\newcommand{\NodeTwoColsH}[2]{%
   #1\nodepart{two}\hskip -5pt #2%
} 

\newcommand{\NodeTwoColsV}[2]{%
   #1\nodepart{two}\vskip -5pt #2%
} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
         sibling distance = 2.5cm,
         every node/.style = {
            draw
         },
         split/.style = {
            rectangle split draw splits=false,
            rectangle split,
            draw,
            rectangle split parts=2
         },
         v split/.style = {
            split
         },
         h split/.style = {
            split,
            rectangle split horizontal
         }
   ]

   \node{root}
   child { node[h split] {\NodeTwoColsH{Left}{Right}} }
   child { node[h split] {\NodeTwoColsH{Left}{Right}} 
      child { node[v split]  {\NodeTwoColsV{Up}{Down}} }
      child { node[v split]  {\NodeTwoColsV{Up}{Down}} }
   };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under ordinary circumstances node contents are put in a `TeX` horizontal box. But horizontal boxes cannot contain commands like `\vskip` so

```
\hbox{A \vskip-5pt B}
```

will produce an error. This is because `TeX` is in "internal horizontal mode" inside the `\hbox` and vertical commands (e.g., `\vskip`) will produce an error (a useful reference for this kind of stuff is "TeX by Topic" by Victor Eijkhout which is freely available on the internet).

But how does this help with `TikZ`? I suppose the cleanest way to get `\vskip` to work inside a node is to set the `text width` of the node so that the contents are first placed inside a vertical box where `\vskip` can be used.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={
  rectangle split, 
  rectangle split draw splits=false, 
  rectangle split parts=2, draw, text width=1.5cm}]

\node at (0,0) {Top\nodepart{two} Bottom};
\node at (2,0) {Top\nodepart{two}\vskip-10pt Bottom};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]